# How to find a row using one column and return the value of that same row in another column

Tags: excel

I've been all over excel & the web and the lookup function seems like it should work but it doesn't as far as I can tell.

I have to Excel tables (Table1, Table2)

Both tables have a column named WO

All I want to do is be able to search Table1 to see if it contains a matching WO from table2 then fill the value of another column from Table1.

I've tried LOOKIP, VLOOKUP, .. ive put the WO column on the leftmost side of the table and sorted ascending ... no matter what i've tried the restults are either WRONG or I just get a bunch of #REF or VALUE! errors ...

it seems like a really simple task to me that excel should be able to do .. I mean if I could write it as an SQL query .. it would be as easy as creating an inner join on WO and grabbing the value from the other column ... Why is this so hard to do in excel?

or am I missing something completely ?

[image: Table1]

[image: Table2]

When I use the Formula ' =LOOKUP([WO Num],Table1[WO'#],Table1[Comment]) ' in the Comment col of Table2 I get the following results

[image: Results from Lookup]

Comment: so you tried `LOOKUP(val, column1name, column2name)` and that didn't work? also, you made sure that you are using fixed ranges (e.g. `$A$4:$A$20` not `A4:A20`)?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected results?  Also can you include specifically what you've tried and why the results were incorrect?

Comment: tried it .. it works but its wrong .. i'll edit the post with some data

Comment: This formula works for me: `=VLOOKUP([@[WO Num]],Table1[#All],3,FALSE)`

Comment: THANK YOU! .. that seems to work! .. i'm not sure why, but im sure that's because I don't fully understand some of the operators yet .. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use MATCH and INDEX.

```
=MATCH(WOValueFromTable2,WOColumnFromTable1,0)
```

will return the row number of the first matching WO value from Table1

you then can use that with the INDEX function to get the corresponding value:

```
=INDEX(AnotherColumnFromTable1, MATCH(WOValueFromTable2,WOColumnFromTable1,0))
```

As an example, this formula entered into Sheet2 B2, would lookup the Value in A1, in Sheet1's Column A, and return the corresponding value from Sheet1's B column

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0))
```

---

Try this sample in a new spreadsheet.

[image]

Type all the values in.  The second Size column get the following formula in Cell E2, and then copy it down to E3 and E4

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D2,A:A,0))
```

Comment: This also provides incorrect results :( .. although more correct .. what this does is repeat the last value matched in rows that follow but do not have a match ...

Comment: Example posted above.  Index Match is much more powerful than the VLOOKUP, it just takes some practice

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get this one to work as well by using 
=INDEX(Table14610[Comment], MATCH([WO Num],Table14610[WO'#],0))
the zero or type on the end of the MATCH function indicating EXACT Match solves the issue of repeating previous values.